# Can't use OrientDB sequence in 2.2.16

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I've download community 2.2.16 and I'm trying to use sequence in the following way:

```
DROP SEQUENCE idseq
CREATE SEQUENCE idseq TYPE CACHED START 1 INCREMENT 1 CACHE 20
SELECT SEQUENCE('idseq').next() from V LIMIT 20
```

But I can't get any values (it's working on 2.2.15)
In addition, I know the sequence created since when I'm trying to recreate the index it throws me an error:

> Sequence 'IDSEQ' already exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that because my DB was empty the way I tried to select values from sequence didn't work and retunes an empty result set.

Since there isn't DUAL table like in Oracle,
I changed the query to be:

```
SELECT SEQUENCE('idseq').next() from OIdentity LIMIT 20
```